# Any possible in paypal Auto redirect using php

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment-gateway

If there are any possible to redirect paypal without click "Return to Store" Link using php script? Not in paypal Account. using only PHP script or JavaScript.

Because I am sending more parameters in thanks page url.

Please Advise.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that be cross site scripting

Answer (score 2):

With Website Payments you can.

To set up Auto Return:

1. Log in and click the Profile subtab under My Account.
2. Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences.
3. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
4. Enter the Return URL. Note: You must meet the Return URL requirements in order to set up Auto Return.

**[Docs here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside)**

Comment: useful information but i need how to auto redirect using Script. please advise

Answer (score 0):

With standard payment buttons or a basic HTML checkout you'll have to rely on their auto-return system or the user clicking the link.

If you want more control over that you can  use the [Express Checkout API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec), in which case the user is always guaranteed to return to your site prior to completing the checkout flow so you can handle any pre or post payment processing within that flow directly.

Since you're working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It will make this a breeze for you, and if you need help getting setup I can offer 30 min of free training, which is generally more than enough to get you familiar with the library and integrating pretty much any PayPal API you want into your project(s).

Comment: If any other possibles in paypal auto returns. using php only. because i am using 5 payment in my website. all pages returns multi different values and return multi pages. So if any script available please provide me

Comment: I already told you, Express Checkout will do what you want and you can use PHP to handle all of that.